# Salesforce code kata

Tags: bestpractice

Personally I find the [repetitive execution of some simple exercise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_%28programming%29) very helpful to me: a good way to learning.

Even if I'm totally ok with programming (java, javascript) I'm totally new to salesforce, apex and visualforce and I'm asking here some nice exercises to train myself. Something like: trigger handler class, recursive trigger, single sign on with js, something to understand the bulk safe thing, some apex/visualforce recurrent design pattern, etc..

What do you advice?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Salesforce Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead) - it's a fun way of learning key Force.com concepts with lots of interesting challenges and there's a nice gamification interface to it so you don't feel bored.